# Oracle syntax >= :1 means

Tags: oracle

Can someone tell me what oracle syntax >= :1 means?
Example

```
Select * from someTable s WHERE (TRUNC(s.ShippedOn)) >= :1
```

in this example  `ShippedOn` is a NUMBER(20,10)

thanks
Niall

Comment: :1 - this is parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Select` statement is dynamic sql statement and `(TRUNC(s.ShippedOn)) >= :1` is means `(TRUNC(s.ShippedOn))` is greater than or equal to bind variable value which you will pass at run time.
[More info in this page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#LNPLS011) .

Comment: A bind variable does not necessarily imply dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 3):

It means greater than or equal to a bound varable